# Erro de argumento em python 3.7

Tags: python

Então, eu ja tentei de todas as formas e cada vez ta dando um erro diferente então decidi postar aqui

[image: Eu tenho que resolver essa questão]

Eu estou recebendo o erro :

> line 66, in 
>       desconto = float(print(f"O valor a vista com desconto é de {preco * 0.90}"))
>   TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Porém ele ainda imprime uma parte do código.
quando coloco 1000 e 10 como valores ele me retorna

> O valor a vista com desconto é de 900.0

```
preco = float(input("Valor da Mercadoria : "))
parcelas = float(input("Em quantos parcelas você quer dividir ? "))
desconto = float(print(f"O valor a vista com desconto é de {preco * 0.90}"))
parcela = float(f"Parcelado em {parcelas}x o valor fica de {preco // parcelas} por mês ")
comissao = float(f"Se a venda for a vista o vendedor recebe {desconto * 0.05}")
comissao_parcelado = float(f"Se a venda for parcelada o vendedor recebe {parcela *0.05}")
```

Comment: Coloca as funções amigo..

Answer (score 1):

A função print devolve None. O ideal seria utilizar formatação de strings.

```
desconto = float(preco * 0.90)
print("O valor a vista com desconto é de {:.2f}".format(desconto))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta dessa forma:

```
preco = float(input('Informe o valor do produto R$: '))
parcelamento = int(input('De seja parcelar em 3x sem juros ? [1]- SIM 
[2] - NAO : '))
valor_a_vista = preco - (preco * 0.1)
if parcelamento == 1:
  print(f'O valor das parcelas ficou em R${preco/3:.2f}')
  print(f'O valor da comissao do vendedor foi de R${preco * 0.05}')
else:
  print(f'O valor a vista recebe um desconto de 10%, o valor ficou em R${valor_a_vista:.2f}')
  print(f'O valor da comissao do vendedor foi de R${valor_a_vista * 0.05}')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
preco = float(input("Valor da Mercadoria : ")) 
parcelas = int(input("Em quantos parcelas você quer dividir ? ")) 
valor_desconto = preco*0.9 
print("O valor a vista com desconto é de R${} \n\n".format(valor_desconto)) 
parcela = preco/parcelas 
print("Parcelado em {}x o valor fica de R${} por mês \n\n".format(parcelas, parcela)) 
comissao_vista = valor_desconto*0.05 
print("Se a venda for a vista o vendedor recebe R${} \n\n".format(comissao_vista)) 
comissao_parcelado = preco*0.05 
print("Se a venda for parcelada o vendedor recebe R${} \n\n".format(comissao_parcelado))
```